# Regex to insert EN space

Tags: adobe-indesign, regex

Indesign CS5.

I'm trying to perfect a regular expression to quickly replace the single-space from raw text to the EN space.  I'm using the following:

```
(\w)([.!?])(['"]{0,1}) {1,}(['"]{0,1})(\u)
```

Replacing to:

```
$1$2$3~>$4$5
```

This should have captured and replaced the space with an EN space the following tests:

```
work. To
work! To
work." To
work.' 'To
work." "To
```

etc.  I recognize it's not perfect as `work.' "To` would get through it, but that would be picked up in the editing sweeps.  Please ignore that and similar conditions.

My problem is the replacement is coming out as...

```
work. $5o
```

The RegEx is finding text perfectly.  If it finds `work." "To`, it replaces the space with an EN-space perfectly.  Anything else isn't replacing correctly.

It appears that the `(['"]{0,1})` expressions, since they're capturing nothing, are not having their relevant $# (e.g., $3) variable set.  However, if that's the case, I expected to see `work. $4$5o` as the replacement for the `work. To` test.

Is there a workaround for this, or am I condemned to running a series of RegEx replacements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to change a regular space `\s` for an EN space I think is more simple:

```
(?<=\.|!|"|')\s(?=.|"|')
```

search al the regular spaces `\s` preceded by a dot `\.` , `!`,  `"` or `'` and behind a character `.`, `"` or `'`

and change it for an EN space

```
~>
```

[image]

---

Actually the second part is redundant, because " and ' are also characters, it must be:

```
(?<=\.|!|"|')\s(?=.)
```

If the rule is the `\s` behind a letter or `"` or `'` :

```
(?<=\.|!|"|')\s(?=\u|\l|"|')
```

If the letter is always an uppercase :

```
(?<=\.|!|"|')\s(?=\u|"|')
```

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, I'll be back after I've tested it.  Note that you can't use the whitespace character (`\s`) because it matches the end-of-paragraph, so `\s{1,}` will collapse paragraphs.  that's why I'm using a simple space (which, in my case, is predictable).

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: I'm using `(?<=\.|!|"|') {1,}(?=\u|\l|"|')`, but it's matching `work" to`, which it cannot do.  I'll try your last RegEx in your current answer.

Comment: Nope.  `(?<=\.|!|"|')\s(?=\u|"|')` matches end-of-paragraph and collapses paragraphs.  `(?<=\.|!|"|') {1,}(?=\u|"|')` fixes that problem, but it's still matching `work" to`, which it cannot do.  The `[.?!]` preceding the space between sentences is mandatory.

Comment: Delete the lowercase: \l, the last answer updated

Comment: I think I can help you better if you put all the text possibilities, with ending paragraphs and text options

Comment: All you need do is look at my original RegEx.  It matches what I need perfectly.  It's the replacement results that are problematic because somethings wrong with what InDesign is doing during the replacement.

Comment: We have a winner!  You must replace `\s` with `{1,}` (there's a single space preceding that left brace) or end-of-paragraph markers are captured and the paragraphs collapsed, but I sincerely appreciate your help working around InDesign's weakness!  Thanks!